# Gql query returning unexpected empty

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

I'm trying to use a query i know is supposed to return a value but it does'nt
and i'm unable to filter using **Type**

heres the query:

```
SELECT Type FROM machinetype WHERE Brand = 'Avant'
```

heres the index serving:

```
Type ▲ , Brand ▲
```

Comment: Can you share the schema of machinetype model?

Comment: be sure you are saving Brand property as indexed.

Answer (score 1):

There are no results returned because you are missing to fetch them.

Python:

```
q = db.GqlQuery("""SELECT Type FROM machinetype WHERE Brand = 'Avant'""")
results = q.fetch(10)
```

or for one result

```
results = q.get()
```

Another possibility is that you modelled Brand as `Text` which makes it non-indexable or you have the code running in production and did never run the query on the development server and the index was not created.

Comment: im doing this in the datastore viewer so thats not the problem